# Piecewise linear secant approximation of the decay function of the perishable products - CPLEX

Tags: product, cplex, piecewise

The decay function is defined below.

[decay function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhAhf.png)

And this non-linear constraint is converted to the piecewise linear function here

[piecewise linear function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyu7N.png)

with L_p is set of linear segment

g_lp = 1 if a linear segment s is used to approximate the decay function

TV_b, TV_e as the transportation time values for the beginning and the
ending, respectively, of a linear segment s

SL_pl, In_pl as the slope and intercept, respectively, of the linear segment s used to approximate the decay function

I have difficulty choosing the suitable parameter slope and intercept of this function. Is there any tips or formula to calculate slope and intercept of this function? Or I have to select by trial and error when applying this constraint in Cplex.

Answer (score 0):

you can interpolate your function . See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/opltipsandtricks/blob/master/interpolatewithpiecewiselinear.mod

```
// linearization of f(x)=1/x through a piecewise linear function
// relying on https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/pwlwithbreakpoints.mod

// our world is not 100% linear so sometimes it's helpful to turn any non linear function
// into a piecewise linear approximation 
int sampleSize=10000;
float s=1;
float e=10;
float x[i in 0..sampleSize]=s+(e-s)*i/sampleSize;
int nbSegments=5;
float x2[i in 0..nbSegments]=(s)+(e-s)*i/nbSegments;
float y2[i in 0..nbSegments]=1/x2[i];  // y=f(x)
float firstSlope=0;
 float lastSlope=0;
 
 tuple breakpoint // y=f(x)
 {
  key float x;
  float y;
 }
 
 sorted { breakpoint } breakpoints={<x2[i],y2[i]> | i in 0..nbSegments};
 
 float slopesBeforeBreakpoint[b in breakpoints]=
 (b.x==first(breakpoints).x)
 ?firstSlope
 :(b.y-prev(breakpoints,b).y)/(b.x-prev(breakpoints,b).x);
 
 pwlFunction f=piecewise(b in breakpoints)
 { slopesBeforeBreakpoint[b]->b.x; lastSlope } (first(breakpoints).x, first(breakpoints).y);
 
 assert forall(b in breakpoints) abs(f(b.x)-b.y)<=0.001;
 
 float maxError=max (i in 0..sampleSize) abs(1/x[i]-f(x[i]));
 float averageError=1/(sampleSize+1)*sum (i in 0..sampleSize) abs(1/x[i]-f(x[i]));
```